# Could we run the SAME do_action multiple times on the same page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wish to call the SAME

`do_action('get_url', $product_id)`

Multiple times on a page in a for loop with different values in the argument.
Is that possible? Or WordPress just allows one-time execution of `do_action` on one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a `do_action()` as many times as you want, it's pretty common to see actions performed multiple times.

For example take WordPress's own [`delete_user`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_user) action, it gets called every time an user gets deleted. If you were to delete 4 users, it would be called 4 times.